# UWP .NET Native Issue

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, prism, .net-native

I am using Prism 6 for UWP and Microsoft.NetCore.Uwp 5.2.2. I faced with issue in Release version that I cannot use reflection.

I have such objects as `IDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>`. How to add policy in default.rd.xml for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, we recently had a similar issue with `IDictionary`, see [here](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/424). I don't know if the error message is similar to yours, but the solution in our case was to add runtime directives in the *.rd.xml* file similar to this:

```
<Type Name="System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary{System.String,System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection{System.String}}" MarshalStructure="Excluded" />
```

Comment: thank you, that is helped. The issue was not exactly in MarshalStructure policy, I just needed to know the syntax

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I run a project under the release mode which contains the `IDictionary<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>` objects, and I don't meet any errors or exceptions. My OS version is build 14393 and I tested it on local machine.

Since I'm not sure what error or exception you got, you can try to add the following collection relative policies to `default.rd.xml`.

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />    

<!--Add your application specific runtime directives here.--> 
<Namespace Name="System.Collections.ObjectModel" >
 <TypeInstantiation Name="ReadOnlyCollection" 
       Arguments="ContosoClient.DataModel.ProductGroup" Serialize="Public"/> 
 <TypeInstantiation Name="ObservableCollection"
       Arguments="ContosoClient.DataModel.ProductItem" Serialize="Public" />
 <TypeInstantiation Name="ReadOnlyObservableCollection"
       Arguments="ContosoClient.DataModel.ProductGroup" Serialize="Public" />     
</Namespace>
```

More details about `rd.xml` configuration file please reference [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600639(v=vs.110).aspx). If you got the `MissingMetadataException` in some reflection scenarios you can follow [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/21/net-native-deep-dive-help-i-hit-a-missingmetadataexception/) to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. The issue is that I use this property to save it when app suspends and terminates. I don't know if you familiar with Prism library, but I use `[ReatorableState]` attribute above all properties that I want to be saved. The prism Session state service uses this attribute. I am getting `InvalidDataContractAttribute exception`